# MIPS converting character in $a0 to upper case

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32, mips64

I'm trying to convert a single character from lowercase to uppercase. But seemingly, nothing is happening:

```
############################################################################
 Transforming lowercase character a-z to uppercase A-Z.

 $a0 = the address of the character 
############################################################################      
uppercase:

  lb $t1, ($a0)       #Load byte into $t1
  beq $t1, 0, exit    #Exit if ends
  blt $t1, 'a', exit  #Exit if less than a
  bgt $t1, 'z', exit  #Exit if greater than z
  sub $t1, $t1, 32    #If lowercase, subtract 32
  sb $t1, ($a0)       #Store it back 
  jr $ra  

exit:
  jr $ra
```

I have tried many different solutions. I think my issue is getting what is in $a0 so it can be used correctly afterwards.

Comment: What do you see when you single-step through this in the debugger?  Which of the three branches is taken when they shouldn't be?  (Simplifications: note that `0 < 'a'` so you don't need to check for it separately.  Also, the `exit:` label can be on the same `jr $ra` that you'd reach via fallthrough.)

Comment: I check the box for Bkpt (breakpoint) in Mars but when I run the program it doesnt stop there. :S

Comment: Then set a breakpoint on the first instruction and single step.  Or else your main program isn't even calling this function.  So this isn't a [mcve].  Use your debugger to single step whatever it is running.

Comment: You gave me a good hint here! I had a syscall in the function that ran before this, so this code was never reached. Thanks!